# Is Silver St. Cloud Aware of Theo Galavan's Intentions?

Tags: dc, gotham

When Theo Galavan was originally introduced in Gotham's second season Rise of the Villains, his role was largely unknown. However, in episode 5 entitled "Scarification", the episode ends with Theo expressing that he wishes to kill Bruce Wayne, who he got close to when he 'saved' young Bruce from Jerome Valeska (I placed saved in quotations since Jerome was one of Theo's accomplices) in episode 3 entitled "Rise of the Villains: The Last Laugh". The following episode, entitled "Strike Force" introduced Silver St. Cloud as Theo's niece and potential love interest for Bruce. However, I am curious: does Silver have genuine feelings towards Bruce or is she simply trying to please her uncle?

Comment: I am voting to close this as primarily opinion based, as this is an ongoing work, and Silver's state of mind has not been extensively explored as yet.

Comment: Per our policy on [future works](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based) this should be cloosed as opinion based; if/when it becomes answerable, please feel free to flag it for moderator attention and/or bring it up on meta and it will get reopened.

Comment: You claim to have, quote, "a policy on future work" when it comes to not one, but two Gotham-related questions I have recently posted, yet in the Batman-v-Superman section of this site, I have seen four well-liked questions regarding the upcoming film. Just thought I'd call you on being so obviously biased.

Comment: @ToadX59 If you believe policies are being applied inconsistently, you should raise your concerns [on meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Silver is in on Galavan's scheme. This was revealed in "Mommy's Little Monster":

> **Galavan:** There will be plenty of time for unleashing hell, and parties, once Bruce Wayne has signed over his company, and met his unfortunate destiny. Until then, I need focus... *[to Silver]* and Bruce to become fond of you; his trust will be crucial when the time comes. I need you to ensure that no-one else is whispering in his ear until I make my offer.
>
> **Silver:** *[Raises her pinky finger]* See this finger? I've got little Bruce wrapped tight around it
>
> **Galavan:** What a vixen you've become. You make me *very* proud.
>
> <sup><sub>*Gotham* Season 2 Episode 7: "Rise of the Villains: Mommy's Little Monster"</sub></sup>

Whether or not she has, or will develop, real feelings for Bruce remains to be seen.